# Refactoring a function and variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm pretty new to any coding, so I'm sorry if this problem seems easily searched, but I'm not sure what to look for here.

What I am trying to do here is create div and put it right before the "level" div (or var header). Then I want put an image in that div. Eventually I want to put three images in there so I tried to refactor a bit so it would not be one long function (I'm sure this isn't DRY, but baby steps). The code below doesn't work because "medalDiv" is not defined. When I insert the code from awardTimeMedal() instead of calling the function, it works fine. I'm not sure if this is a scope issue, but I thought since medalDiv was defined in awardMedal() that awardTimeMedal would have access to it.

```
//doesn't work
function awardMedal(){
    var medalDiv = document.createElement("div");
    awardTimeMedal();
    var header = document.getElementById("level");
    header.insertBefore(medalDiv, header.childNodes[0]);

}

function awardTimeMedal(){
    var timeMedal = document.createElement("img");
    timeMedal.src = properties.MEDAL_OFF;
    timeMedal.className = "medals";
    medalDiv.appendChild(timeMedal);
    return medalDiv;
}

//works
function awardMedal(){
    var medalDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var timeMedal = document.createElement("img");
    timeMedal.src = properties.MEDAL_OFF;
    timeMedal.className = "medals";
    medalDiv.appendChild(timeMedal);
    var header = document.getElementById("level");
    header.insertBefore(medalDiv, header.childNodes[0]);
}
```

I've also tried it without a "return medalDiv" statement.

Thanks. I'm sorry if I didn't follow any proper etiquette and any help is appreciated.

Edit: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

var medalDiv is local to awardMedal and used in awardTimeMedal. Put it in global scope to have access.

Answer (score 0):

Update the former function

```
function awardMedal(){
    var medalDiv = document.createElement("div");
    awardTimeMedal(medalDiv);
    var header = document.getElementById("level");
    header.insertBefore(medalDiv, header.childNodes[0]);

}

function awardTimeMedal(medalDiv){
    var timeMedal = document.createElement("img");
    timeMedal.src = properties.MEDAL_OFF;
    timeMedal.className = "medals";
    medalDiv.appendChild(timeMedal);
    return medalDiv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you invoke `awardTimeMedal()` you must store the return value in a variable for it to be accessible from the calling process i.e., `awardMedal()`. So,

```
var ref = awardTimeMedal();
```

Now you can use ref to append to the correct element. 
FYI, whenever you use var or function keyword, it creates a new lexical scope in JavaScript. This means that the current scope is strictly tied to the newly introduced scope. When you try to access a variable or reference within that scope the compiler looks at the scope's stack and if the referred variable is not found, then in the parent scope. The parent scope usually resolves to the document if, not explicitly guarded against.

Answer (score -1):

The main reason why your first function does not work is because `awardTimeMedal` does not have access to `medalDiv`

I belief a better approach would be to return `awardTimeMedal` element and append it in `awardMedal` function, like what I've done below:

```
function awardMedal(){
    var medalDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var timeMedal = awardTimeMedal();
    medalDiv.appendChild(timeMedal);

    var header = document.getElementById("level");
    header.insertBefore(medalDiv, header.childNodes[0]);
}

function awardTimeMedal(){
    var timeMedal = document.createElement("img");
    timeMedal.src = properties.MEDAL_OFF;
    timeMedal.className = "medals";
    return timeMedal;
}
```